# php: rename duplicate keys by giving number in foreach

Tags: arrays, foreach, on-duplicate-key

i have a form data and the data's array like this:

```
$datas=array("x-1","y-2","y-2","y-3","t-1");
```

my foreach loop:

```
    foreach($datas as $x => $data){
    $data=explode("-",$data);
    if($data[0]==$data[0]+1){$n=1;}else{$n=0;}
    $keys[$x]=$data[0].$n++;
    $vals[$x]=$data[1];
}
```

i couldn't write the true code, my 3rd line is wrong i think (if($data[0]=$data[0]+1){$n="1";}else{$n="";})
so, i wanna rename the duplicate keys by giving number. my output should be like this:

```
x=1 y1=1    y2=2    y3=2    t1=1
```

Comment: i could not find the solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
     $datas=array("x-1","y-2","y-2","y-3","t-1");

     $i=0;
     $n=1;
     foreach($datas as $x => $data){
     $data=explode("-",$data);
     $data2=explode("-",$datas[$i+1]);
     if($data[0]==$data2[0])
      {  
      $keys[$x]=$data[0].$n; 
      $n=$n+1;
      }
      else
     {
     $keys[$x]=$data[0].$n; 
     $n=0;
     }

       $vals[$x]=$data[1];
    $i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has error you use `=` Which will assign value , not compare it.
also `n` should be integer not string 
To fix that

```
  foreach($datas as $x => $data){
    $data=explode("-",$data);
    if($keys[$x]==$keys[$x+1]){$n=1;}else{$n=0;}
    $keys[$x]=$data[0].$n++;
    $vals[$x]=$data[1];
}
```

Comment: ty and sorry i changed my code, i wanna use numbering for $data[0] and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($data[0]=$data[0]+1){$n="1";}else{$n="";}
```

Use == instead of = for the if statements

Comment: i changed it, but i cannot give number to the duplicate keys.