# Duplicate words in PHP

Tags: php

I have probably information about whether it is available in PHP to detect a duplicate and a book about not removing it and adding it to -1, -2, -3

Example:

```
$string = 'H4,H4,H3,WY21W,W5W,W5W,WY21W,W21/5W,W21/5W,W21W,W16W,W5W';
```

Result:

```
$output = 'H4,H4-1,H3,WY21W,W5W,W5W-1,WY21W-1,W21/5W,W21/5W-1,W21W,W16W,W5W-2'
```

Comment: Yes you can do that, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word)

Comment: @Miaan - IMO that question indeed looks the same, but the answer does not fit in the scope of this question. This question is also about adding some data after the words.

Comment: I was looking for such an example, however, I can not find. I just wrote that it removes duplicate values.

Comment: @Danko12 - Please don't forget to mention everything you did, so we don't repeat those steps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php: rename duplicate keys by giving number in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540944/php-rename-duplicate-keys-by-giving-number-in-foreach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = 'H4,H4,H3,WY21W,W5W,W5W,WY21W,W21/5W,W21/5W,W21W,W16W,W5W';
$parts = explode(',', $string); // split by comma
$used = []; // array to count the number of occurrences
$result = []; // array to take the "new" elements

foreach($parts as $part) {
  if(isset($used[$part])) { // if there is an entry in the counter array already,
                            // increment it by one,
    $used[$part]++;
  }
  else {                    // else initialize with 0
    $used[$part] = 0;
  }
  // put part into new array, append -(counter) if counter > 0
  $result[] = $part . ($used[$part] ? '-'.$used[$part] : '');
}

echo implode(',', $result); // join together with comma
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same as misorude's answer.

```
<?php

$string = 'H4,H4,H3,WY21W,W5W,W5W,WY21W,W21/5W,W21/5W,W21W,W16W,W5W';
$values  = explode(',', $string);

foreach($values as $k => $value)
    if($counts[$value] = !isset($counts[$value]) ? 0 : $counts[$value]-1)
        $values[$k] = $value . $counts[$value];

print implode(',', $values);
```

Output:

```
H4,H4-1,H3,WY21W,W5W,W5W-1,WY21W-1,W21/5W,W21/5W-1,W21W,W16W,W5W-2
```